# how can I run a single test in my terminal

Tags: laravel, terminal, phpunit

I run my test with vendor/bin/phpunit and its working fine.
How can I run a single test in my terminal..

suppose I need to run this test only how can I do that?

```
  public function demoTest()
  {
    Book::create([
        'title' => 'cool title',
        'author_id' => 1,
    ]);

    $this->assertCount(1, Book::all());
  }
```

I use something like this but didnt work

```
phpunit --filter demoTest
```

if anyone know the answer please help me

Comment: phpunit --filter methodName path/to/file.php    so here path means tests/unit/test.php   the what is to what I need to use to 'to'.

Comment: vendor/bin/phpunit --filter an_author_id_is_recorded works for me